# Batch script, copying filename to a txt file

Tags: batch-file

Could anyone assist, i crate a batch script that will create bunch of txt files from the list i have, the txt then needs to contain a few lines on text and parts of it will need to have the name of a file.
So eg.

```
 mkdir file1.txt
```

then the .txt file needs to have:

```
 this file contains info
 owner of the file is 'file.txt'
 data for this file is in C:\Users\'file.txt'
```

Please let me know should this not be clear enough 
Thanks

---

(copy/formatted from OP's comment - OP: Use the EDIT link to edit your question (judiciously, of course))

so far i have written

```
@echo off 
for %%a in (*.txt) do type customer=customer fromAddress=email@domain.com andOrAddress=OR toAddress=email@domain.com outputPath=E:\Exgest\customer\email@domain.com outputFormat=MIME customHeaders=true fromDate=20030901 toDate=20101231 >> (*.txt)
```

This failed to add a text and only created *.txt file in this folder. Then I tried running 
    copy >> email@domain.com

for each email address in the list, and then 
    copy con >> name of each file

which just added syntax is correct to the txt file. Sorry guys, I am very new at batch scripting so.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried, don't expect others to give effort if you haven't

Comment: Also please elaborate by giving a full example

Comment: so far i have wrote 
@echo off
for %%a in (*.txt) do type 
customer=customer
fromAddress=email@domain.com 
andOrAddress=OR
toAddress=email@domain.com 
outputPath=E:\Exgest\customer\email@domain.com
outputFormat=MIME
customHeaders=true
fromDate=20030901
toDate=20101231 >> (*.txt)
this failed to add a text and only created *.txt file in this folder
then i tried running
copy >> email@domain.com for each email address in the list, and then copy con >> name of each file which just added syntax is correct to the txt file.
Sorry guys, i am very new at batch scripting so...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write something in a file, then you need to write this in a batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO.this file contains info>>file.txt
ECHO.owner of the file is 'file.txt'>>file.txt
ECHO.data for this file is in C:\Users\'file.txt'>>file.txt
```

Before `ECHO.` write what do you want to be sended to an file with any extension.
Before what do you want to write in that file, write `>` if you want to keep only a single line writed, and `>>` if you want to write more lines in that file.

So if you have:

```
ECHO.thing>>file.txt
ECHO.thing2>file.txt
```

`file.txt` will looks like this:

```
thing2
```

I hope that this helps you.

P.S.: Sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0):

What you intend to do is unclear.

What your code seems to want to do is to append "customer=customer fr...01 toDate=20101231" to each existing .TXT file. The correct syntax for this would be

```
@echo off 
for %%a in (*.txt) do ECHO customer=customer fromAddress=email@domain.com andOrAddress=OR toAddress=email@domain.com outputPath=E:\Exgest\customer\email@domain.com outputFormat=MIME customHeaders=true fromDate=20030901 toDate=20101231 >>"%%a"
```

which should add the extra line at the end of each `.txt` file.

Note the changes - `ECHO` not `TYPE` and  `>>"%%a"` since the metavariable `%%a` will contain the filename of the files `*.txt` - and the "quotes" ensure that `"filenames containing spaces.txt"` are processed properly.

Answer (score 0):

@user2782162 you need to edit your question and be more specific.
I've created the below batch based on what 'I think' you are trying to do.

Please let us know if this is what you want?
Also...i'm sure @Magoo could make this a lot simpler(you're a wiz at it).

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET listloc=list.txt

:start
FOR /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a IN (%listloc%) DO CALL :process1 %%a
ECHO.
ECHO List finished - Press any key to close.
PAUSE >nul
GOTO :eof


:process1
SET fname=%2
IF "%2"=="" GOTO :eof
:process2
ECHO %1=%2 >>%fname%.txt
SHIFT
SHIFT
IF NOT "%2"=="" GOTO process2
GOTO :eof
```

This is assuming that your input file 'list.txt' is arranged like the below...with all the info for each 'new file' on individual lines like this....

### Contents of list.txt

```
 customer=hello1 fromAddress=email1@domain.com andOrAddress=OR1 toAddress=email1@domain.com outputPath=E:\Exgest\customer\email@domain1.com outputFormat=MIME1 customHeaders=true1 fromDate=200309011 toDate=201012311
 customer=hello2 fromAddress=email2@domain.com andOrAddress=OR2 toAddress=email2@domain.com outputPath=E:\Exgest\customer\email@domain2.com outputFormat=MIME2 customHeaders=true2 fromDate=200309012 toDate=201012312
 customer=hello3 fromAddress=email3@domain.com andOrAddress=OR3 toAddress=email3@domain.com outputPath=E:\Exgest\customer\email@domain3.com outputFormat=MIME3 customHeaders=true3 fromDate=200309013 toDate=201012313
```

The Batch will read the 'list.txt' 1 row at a time.
It will use the value for "customer" on each row as the name for the new file.

Example below show what the output for the first row will look like..

### Contents of hello1.txt

```
 customer=hello1 
 fromAddress=email1@domain.com 
 andOrAddress=OR1 
 toAddress=email1@domain.com 
 outputPath=E:\Exgest\customer\email@domain1.com 
 outputFormat=MIME1 
 customHeaders=true1 
 fromDate=200309011 
 toDate=201012311
```